# Xamarin Forms: CachingStrategy not available

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin Forms i have added a Listview:

```
<ListView x:Name="StudentView"  RowHeight="55"  SeparatorVisibility="None">
```

Why the CachingStrategy property is not available? If i try to add that property, intellisense not show that property and seems not available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Visual Studio `CachingStrategy` IntelliSense don't work properly.

Try writing it manually:

```
<ListView CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
```